# Flash builder 4 - Build into different output folders

Tags: apache-flex, compilation, flash-builder

Can I configure Flash Builder 4 to build into different folders? Something like: build applications files into "folder a" and modules files into "folder b"?

Thanks,
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different projects for each application, then (by default( the applications are already building into different folders.  It would be possible--although uncommon--to set multiple projects to use the same bin folder.

Flash Builder, for all intents and purposes, was created under the assumption that there would be only one application for each project.  The only time I have multiple applications in a single project is if it is a "Scratch" project for testing different ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In this case, I have a single project and I want to build some packages into output folder A and other packages into output folder B. Is that possible?

I´m using ASP MVC server, so I want to builder my flex application into "Views" folder, and my flex modules into "Content" folder. Otherwise, my flex application can't access my module files.

Comment: When you said build in the question, I assumed you meant "compile".  You can easily create components in different folders.  If you're building "Flex Modules" ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/modules/Module.html ) usually each module is generated from a separate project.  but, once you export a release build you can put it anywhere you want.